# How to improve / correct my technique below to implement image slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following list

```
<div id="imgrt">
<ul id="if">
  <li><img src="../pictures/album/20-c-44.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="../pictures/album/21-c-44.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="../pictures/album/u1-c-44.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have a button which which on click is going to animate by pushing each image to the left margin.
What i sort of did was was

```
function animateImages(iD, index) {
    var j = passedIndex;
    iD.children().each(function(index){

        if (passedIndex == index)
        jquery(this).animate(.........);
        return (index+1); 
    });
}
var nextIndex = 0;
jquery('#next').click(function() {
                            nextIndex = animateImages(jquery('#li',nextIndex);
                           });
```

My question

1. if you notice this is kind of bad implementation (atleast am guessing so, please correct if wrong), i'm doing a function call to animateImages which does nothing but just querying a jquery(this) element in the list and breaking after animating. How can i do it efficiently?

Thanks in advance.

[Addition Notes] - just noticed the last part of jquery.each() where they have mentioned to exit early. Basically i want to exit early in the loop but the early is after every iteration. So it will be like return (somthing)

Please suggest some better ways for this. As mentioned above, when i click a button, the control will jump to the animateImages function which will navigate through the element in the list, animate the image and return the index in the list. On next click, it will go to the same list, and check for the index, and if index matches the list element, animate it and return the new index and so on.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the behavior that you are looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by "`break` after every list element"? `break` (in languages that have it) is used to exit loop constructs early... you can't do it after every iteration, because once you `break` there aren't any more iterations...

Comment: Why do you want to `break`? Does that mean you always want to stop after the first iteration? Why not just select the first element then and animate it? (btw. you just have to read the documentation of `$.each` a bit more carefully and then you know how to exit earlier ;))

Comment: @Felix Kling et all ahh yea, just noticed the last part of it where they have mentioned to exit early. Basically yes i want to exit early in the loop but the early is after every iteration. Please suggest some better ways for this. As mentioned above, when i click a button, the control will jump to the animateImages function which will navigate through the element in the list, animate the image and return the index in the list. On next click, it will go to the same list, and check for the index, and if index matches the list element, animate it and return the new index

Comment: Yes i would have to modify the above function to make these changes like function animateImages(iD, index) { ${"li"}.each {// navigate the list, check the index, animate the list element in the index and return index}, my question is is there a better way to do this, rather than making a function call for every click

Comment: @JohnP all i want to do is a image slider. I saw several plugins, but i want to learn jquery the hard way, so doing myself. Please refer to my above comments, i think i specified more elaborately, but please let me know if you want more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified it slightly so that the current image has an id:

```
<div id="imgrt">
<ul id="if">
  <li id="current"><img src="../pictures/album/20-c-44.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="../pictures/album/21-c-44.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="../pictures/album/u1-c-44.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
<a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
```

This way your javascript can look like this:

```
$('#next').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var $current = $('#current');
    $('#current').next().attr('id','temp-curr');
    // animation code
    $current.removeAttr('id');
    $('#temp-curr').attr('id','current');
});
```

The reason I did it this way is so that only ONE element ever has the #current id, this way if any of your other code ties in to it, it won't get confused if it ever runs when there are two elements named current.

I would add your animate code and tie it in to sliding the entire ul element. instead of looping through your entire list every time. Just set a width on the #imgrt and set overflow to hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on this technique, understood how removeAttr and attr can be set dynamically to each elements. works great and helped me find my mistakes. Sorry if the question was very lame, i'm just 2 days into jquery/js and 1 week into html and css.

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help.